# Why can't I get token in response of Huawei Push Kit？

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, token, huawei-mobile-services

please explain me, why response HmsInstanceId.getInstance always empty.
in first time token comes to onNewToken, but why always `String token = HmsInstanceId.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getToken(appId, "HCM");`   empty and how I could get this token?

```
new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String appId = AGConnectServicesConfig.fromContext(MainActivity.this).getString("client/app_id");
                String token = HmsInstanceId.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getToken(appId, "HCM");          
            } catch (Exception e) {


            }
       }
   }.start();
```

and maybe second question:
token assigned to the phone, but if my app has two users, how I could assign token fore each user in one app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why response HmsInstanceId.getInstance always empty. in first time token comes to onNewToken, but why always String token = HmsInstanceId.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getToken(appId, "HCM");   empty and how I could get this token?

The device EMUI version is earlier than 10 returns null, and then the token is returned from the `onNewToken` callback.
You can refer this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-client-dev-0000001050042041-V5?ha_source=hms1).

[image]

> token assigned to the phone, but if my app has two users, how I could assign token fore each user in one app?

Huawei Push tokens are associated with devices and do not differentiate users. However, you can bind a user to a token based on your service. I don't know what your specific application scenario is. Maybe you can try to `getToken` every time you log in and `deleteToken` every time you log out.